# Visual Basic: loaded parallel list boxes with text file substrings, but now items other than lstBox(0) "out of bounds"

Tags: vb.net

The text file contains lines with the year followed by population like:

> 2016, 322690000
>   2015, 320220000
>   etc.

I separated the lines substrings to get all the years in a list box, and all the population amounts in a separate listbox, using the following code:

```
Dim strYearPop As String
Dim intYear As Integer
Dim intPop As Integer

strYearPop = popFile.ReadLine()

intYear = CInt(strYearPop.Substring(0, 4))
intPop = CInt(strYearPop.Substring(5))

lstYear.Items.Add(intYear)
lstPop.Items.Add(intPop)
```

Now I want to add the population amounts together, using the .Items to act as an array.

```
Dim intPop1 As Integer
intPop1 = lstPop.Items(0) + lstPop.Items(1)
```

But I get an error on lstPop.Items(1) and any item other than lstPop.Items(0), due to out of range. I understand the concept of out of range, but I thought that I create an index of several items (about 117 lines in the file, so the items indices should go up to 116) when I populated the list box.

How do i populate the list box in a way that creates an index of list box items (similar to an array)?

Comment: Is it possible You are missing a loop over the file's line? With other words: is the code between `ReadLine()` and `lstPop.Items.Add(intPop)` called more than once?

Answer (score 0):

[I will treat this as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/232762) - please consider reading that after reading this answer.]

What you are missing is the separation of the data from the presentation of the data.

It is not a good idea to use controls to store data: they are meant to *show* the underlying data.

You could use two arrays for the data, one for the year and one for the population count, or you could use a Class which has properties of the year and the count. The latter is more sensible, as it ties the year and count together in one entity. You can then have a List of that Class to make a collection of the data, like this:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Public Class PopulationDatum
        Property Year As Integer
        Property Count As Integer
    End Class

    Function GetData(srcFile As String) As List(Of PopulationDatum)
        Dim data As New List(Of PopulationDatum)
        Using sr As New StreamReader(srcFile)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                Dim thisLine = sr.ReadLine
                Dim parts = thisLine.Split(","c)
                If parts.Count = 2 Then
                    data.Add(New PopulationDatum With {.Year = CInt(parts(0).Trim()), .Count = CInt(parts(1).Trim)})
                End If
            End While
        End Using

        Return data

    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim srcFile = "C:\temp\PopulationData.txt"
        Dim popData = GetData(srcFile)
        Dim popTotal = 0

        For Each p In popData
            lstYear.Items.Add(p.Year)
            lstPop.Items.Add(p.Count)
            popTotal = popTotal + p.Count
        Next

        ' popTotal now has the value of the sum of the populations

    End Sub

End Class
```

If using a List(Of T) is too much, then just use the idea of separating the data from the user interface. It makes processing the data much simpler.